# Why is xargs' exit code different based on the presence of "-I" option?

Tags: grep, find, posix, xargs, exit-code

After reading the xargs [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html), I am unable to understand the difference in exit codes from the following xargs invocations.

(The original purpose was to combine find and grep to check if an expressions exists in ALL the given files when I came across this behaviour)

To reproduce:

(use `>>!` if using zsh to force creation of file)

```
# Create the input files.
echo "a" >> 1.txt   
echo "ab" >> 2.txt

# The end goal is to check for a pattern (in this case simply 'b') inside
# ALL the files returned by a find search. 
find .  -name "1.txt" -o -name "2.txt" | xargs -I {}  grep -q "b"  {}
echo $?
  123  # Works as expected since 'b' is not present in 1.txt

find .  -name "1.txt" -o -name "2.txt" | xargs grep -q "b"
echo $?
  0   # Am more puzzled by why the behaviour is inconsistent
```

The [EXIT_STATUS](http://EXIT_STATUS) section on the man page says:

```
xargs exits with the following status:
0 if it succeeds
123 if any invocation of the command exited with status 1-125
124 if the command exited with status 255
125 if the command is killed by a signal
126 if the command cannot be run
127 if the command is not found
1 if some other error occurred.
```

I would have thought, that `123 if any invocation of the command exited with status 1-125` should apply irrespective of whether or not `-I` is used ?

Could you share any insights to explain this conundrum please?

Comment: I believe I've found the answer in a comment of another question : https://superuser.com/questions/557203/xargs-i-behaviour#comment678705_557230. Details being posted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is evidence of the effect of `-I` option with xargs with the help of a wrapper script which shows the number of invocations:

```
cat ./grep.sh
#/bin/bash

echo "I am being invoked at $(date +%Y%m%d_%H-%M-%S)"
grep $@
```

(the actual command being invoked, in this case `grep` doesn't really matter)

Now execute the same commands as in the question using the wrapper script instead:

```
❯ find .  -name "1.txt" -o -name "2.txt" | xargs -I {}  ./grep.sh -q "b" {}
I am being invoked at 20190410_09-46-29
I am being invoked at 20190410_09-46-30

❯ find .  -name "1.txt" -o -name "2.txt" | xargs ./grep.sh -q "b"
I am being invoked at 20190410_09-46-53
```

---

I have just discovered a comment on the answer of a similar question that answers this question (complete credit to https://superuser.com/users/49184/daniel-andersson for his wisdom):

https://superuser.com/questions/557203/xargs-i-behaviour#comment678705_557230

> Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character. — this is central to understanding the behavior. Without -I, xargs only sees the input as a single field, since newline is not a field separator. With -I, suddenly newline is a field separator, and thus xargs sees three fields (that it iterates over). That is a real subtle point, but is explained in the man page quoted.

```
-I replace-str
   Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments
   with names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do
   not terminate input items; instead the separator is the
   newline character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
```

Based on that,

```
find .  -name "1.txt" -o -name "2.txt"  
#returns
# ./1.txt 
# ./2.txt

xargs -I {}  grep -q "b"  {}
# interprets the above as two separate lines since,
# with -I option the newline is now a *field separator*. 
# So this results in TWO invocations of grep and since one of them fails, 
# the overall output is 123 as documented in the EXIT_STATUS section

xargs grep -q "b"
# interprets the above as a single input field,
# so a single grep invocation which returns a successful exit code of 0 since the pattern was found in one of the files.
```